# How to sleep a process for a vary interval of miliseconds

Tags: c, linux, sleep

I'm reading about `Sleep` `nanosleep` `usleep` but I'm not sure which one to use nor how to use it exactly...

I need to make a process sleep for a `random` number each '10, 20, 30, 40, 50 miliseconds'.

How may I achieve that ?

I'm testing like so:

```
Sleep(rand()%1500);
```

But I'd like to know if it's possible to set that interval in a single line.

Comment: More details: what platform/API are you using?

Comment: For [`nanosleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html) from POSIX 2008 (the current version), you have to generate a number 10000000, 20000000, … and stuff that into the `struct timespec` that you pass to the function (in the `tv_nsec` member; the `tv_sec` member will be 0.  For [`usleep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/usleep.html) from POSIX 2004 (not in POSIX 2008), you need to generate 10000, 20000, … and pass that to the function.  So, basically, you need a random number between 1 and 5 and then multiply appropriately.

Comment: Yeah.. you need to reference your OS API docs and h files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You've to reference the `unistd.h`.
2. Then use the functions `rand()` & `usleep()`.

A sample may be:

```
// edited as @JonathanLeffler advised
...
#include <unistd.h>
...

void foo(int someArgs) {
    ...
    useconds_t sleepTime;

    ...
    // create random int r where 0 <= r < 0x7fffffff
    sleepTime = (useconds_t)(((rand() % 5) + 1) * 10000); 
    usleep(sleepTime);
    ...

    // for a single line preference, following may work it out
    usleep(((rand() % 5) + 1) * 10000);

}
```

Comment: Nominally, you should be using `useconds_t sleepTime;` since `usleep()` takes a `useconds_t` as an argument (see the link in my comment to the question).  Plain old signed `int` would only cause trouble if you're on a machine with 16-bit `int`, which is possible but not plausible.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You're right, `useconds_t sleepTime;` would be a better choice. However, though I've not tested and not 100% sure, the line `sleepTime = rand();` may need a cast in your case, like `sleepTime = (useconds_t) rand();`.

Comment: As long as everything is declared before it is used, the compiler should sort it out, though compiling with GCC and `-Wconversion` may trigger warnings (errors if you use `-Werror` too, as I do habitually).  OTOH, a value in the range 1-5 can be converted safely to any integer type, so any such warning is nit-picking to no purpose — in this context.  In general, such warnings can tell you about problems, but not this time.  And to some extent, my first comment was nit-picking too — it was much more a 'nominal problem' than an actual one.

Comment: @merkez3110 Thanks man. Just don't get exactly the logic with the numbers. What if I want to make a sleep between 80~90milleseconds.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro: Then your single line would be: `usleep(((rand() % 11) + 80) * 1000);` This way, `rand() % 11` will give you a random number b/w 0 and 10; then, adding 80 will make b/t 80 and 90; multiplying with 1000 makes a number b/w 80000 and 90000 nanosec (80 and 90 millisecs) inclusive. **Note:** You'd better revisit the "`%`" operator. I think, the secret you're after is the usage of the **modulus** operator.